# Remove comma between "" in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

How I can remove comma ',' between each " " in a string with C# ?

I have try with:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(input,
@",([^""]$)",String.Empty);
```

but it doesn't work ...

Thank

Comment: Basically your RegEx replaces a comma followed by a character except `"` into an empty string, so... ?

Comment: What do you mean `between each " "`? You mean a string literal?

Comment: For example aaaaaa,bbbbb,cccc,"bbbb, aaaa",aaa,"vv, x" will come:       aaaaaa,bbbbb,cccc,"bbbb aaaa",aaa,"vv x"

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to parse csv data using the wrong tool for the job. have you considered a purpose-built csv parser?

Answer (score 6):

My idea is to split by "quotes" so each uneven-index element will be something between quotations.
Going through those, replacing commas with nothing for them, and then rejoining everything to a single string, should do the trick:

```
var parts = input.Split('"');

for (var i = 1; i < parts.Length; i += 2)
{
    parts[i] = parts[i].Replace(",", "");
}

var result = string.Join("\"", parts);
```

Comment: +1. The neat thing is, this approach should work on escaped CSV quotes, too, since quotes get escaped by doubling them ("this ""is"" a test.").

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Very nice! I was indeed thinking about a case of empty ""'s, but didn't think how good it works with escaped quotes in CSV format. Cool that you pointed it out!

Answer (score 1):

I'm slightly confused on what your input string looks like, but as long as you are trying to do simple replace of commas you could try

```
var result = input.replace(",","");
```

Comment: How is that the answer? It seems from his comment on the question that he only wants to remove the commas that are between quotations.

Comment: I agree with @YoryeNathan this is why I deleted my answer as I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Apparently so did I :( I apologize.

Comment: If the poster takes the accepted answer off I can delete it. But since it's the accepted answer I can't. If what @Yore Nathan understood the question to be is correct, then his answer is right. But if mine solved his problem, obviously he didn't phrase the question right.

Answer (score 0):

```
// extract the fields
    Regex CSVParser = new Regex(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*(?![^\"]*\"))");
    String[] Fields = CSVParser.Split(Test);


    // clean up the fields (remove " and leading spaces)
    for (int i = 0; i < Fields.Length; i++)
    {
        Fields[i] = Fields[i].TrimStart(' ', '"');
        Fields[i] = Fields[i].TrimEnd('"');
    }
```